# File names with spaces in Org link DESCRIPTIONs are not properly exported to html

Tags: org-export, html

Emacs 29.1 (on Windows); Org 9.6.6 manages to export file descriptions as clickable buttons only when the path to the file has no space(s) in it.

Links like these

```
#+caption: File name with spaces
#+attr_html: :width 200
[[../file name.png]]
```

are showing static images whereas

```
[[../file-name.png][file:../file-name.png]]
```

are exported as images and the images are clickable (as described in the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html)), but a following link

```
[[../file name.png][file:../file name.png]]
```

is not properly exported (the image doesn't show up).  What can I do - except to rename involved files?

Comment: FWIW, it should be `[[type:address][description]]`, like what you write in HTML -- address is followed by descriptive text.

Comment: BTW, `[[../file name._pgn_]]`, typo?

Comment: Thank you change it to png.